# How does "secondaryPreferred" work in this scenario?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Suppose there is a *replica set* of three nodes: 1 primary `P` and 2 secondaries `S1` and `S2`. Suppose also that `P` and `S1` are located in one data center `DC1` and `S2` in another data center `DC2`.

Suppose a client is located in `DC1` (i.e. in the same data center as `P` and `S1`) and `S1` is down. Where will the client queries go ? `P` or `S2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`secondaryPreferred` will choose the secondary, even if it's further away (I'm assuming that `S2` has a lower priority because it probably shouldn't be primary, so in your scenario `S2` is the secondary and that it's further away in the latency sense).

You can instead use [tag sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#tag-sets) for [data-center awareness / geographically distributed members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#query-from-geographically-distributed-members) or the [`nearest` read-preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#nearest), which will select the server that is closer, irrespective of whether it's a primary or secondary.

Comment: And is covered directly in the paragraphs following the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondaryPreferred

Answer (score 1):

From the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/):

#### secondaryPreferred

> In most situations, operations read from secondary members, but in situations where the set consists of a single primary (and no other members), the read operation will use the set’s primary.
>
> When the read preference includes a tag set, the client attempts to find a secondary member that matches the specified tag set and directs reads to a random secondary from among the nearest group. If no secondaries have matching tags, the client ignores tags and reads from the primary.
>
> Read operations using the secondaryPreferred mode may return stale data.

---

My guess is that you would get the data from `S2`, since that is what you have asked for with the *preferred* suffix. The `secondary` option excludes the primary entirely but while the `secondaryPreferred` allows for primary to be used in case of no secondaries.

Though by using tags for your servers in the same data center you can make the driver read from primary even though a secondary is present in the rest of the replica set.

Comment: It's not a matter of a guess. As the documentation you quote says, The  use of a tag set can resolve this so that the operations will use the nearest in preference to a remote secondary. This ensures the routing to the secondary rather than the primary. But you probably didn't see the other answer in time.

Comment: Bad phrasing. It is plain as you say.